# The Ads do not get deleted after In-App purchase in Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, ipad

I made an app that a offer only one In-App Purchase to delete the Ads & etc.

I have all the code I need to make the In-App purchase when I test it - the etc works (for example: new modes in the app) but the ads do not get removed.

This is what I tried:

```
if defaults.boolForKey("removeAds") == true {


        canDisplayBannerAds = false
        adBannerView?.delegate = self
        adBannerView?.hidden = true
        adBannerView!.removeFromSuperview()
```

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell what the problem is with such little information surrounding your implementation, but one thing to verify is that you're running any code that affects the UI on the main thread.

For example, you could try surrounding that block of UI-modifying code with a `dispatch_async` block:

```
if defaults.boolForKey("removeAds") == true {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
        self.canDisplayBannerAds = false
        self.adBannerView?.delegate = self
        self.adBannerView?.hidden = true
        self.adBannerView!.removeFromSuperview()
    }
}
```

Please notice also that inside the `dispatch_async` block, you need to reference your properties using `self` to avoid ambiguity.

Comment: I tried it now.. (with the self) and it doesn't work. I still get to see the ads. Tell me what code you need me to bring and I will

Comment: It would be helpful to see where you're adding the adBannerView to the parent view. Also, where is this `if` statement being called? In `viewDidLoad` or somewhere else?

Comment: How can I provide the information about where my adBannerView is in the parent view? And yes, the `if` statement is in the `viewDidLoad`

Comment: If you can show a screenshot of the hierarchy from the Storyboard, that would be helpful. Just a thought, but if this code is only in `viewDidLoad`, it won't be called after the view has already loaded. You could place the code in `viewWillAppear` instead and see if that fixes your issue. Are the ads present throughout the app or only in one view?